# Универсальная защита от xss-атак и sql-инъекций

Tags: взлом

Я не занимаюсь технической поддержкой сайтов, но так уж сложилось, что ко мне часто обращаются за помощью. С одной стороны отказывать неудобно, да и не выгодно с коммерческой точки зрения, с другой за большое спасибо в магазине тоже не расплатишься. Поэтому я решил написать универсальное решение, но столкнулся с некоторыми проблемами. 
Суть решения заключается в том, чтобы отловить данные POST, GET, COOKIE и обработать их еще до того, как сайт произведет с ними какие-либо действия.
Вот собственно сам код

```php
$jsxss="onabort,oncanplay,oncanplaythrough,ondurationchange,onemptied,onended,onerror,onloadeddata,onloadedmetadata,onloadstart,onpause,onplay,onplaying,onprogress,onratechange,onseeked,onseeking,onstalled,onsuspend,ontimeupdate,onvolumechange,onwaiting,oncopy,oncut,onpaste,ondrag,ondragend,ondragenter,ondragleave,ondragover,ondragstart,ondrop,onblur,onfocus,onfocusin,onfocusout,onchange,oninput,oninvalid,onreset,onsearch,onselect,onsubmit,onabort,onbeforeunload,onerror,onhashchange,onload,onpageshow,onpagehide,onresize,onscroll,onunload,onkeydown,onkeypress,onkeyup,altKey,ctrlKey,shiftKey,metaKey,key,keyCode,which,charCode,location,onclick,ondblclick,oncontextmenu,onmouseover,onmouseenter,onmouseout,onmouseleave,onmouseup,onmousemove,onwheel,altKey,ctrlKey,shiftKey,metaKey,button,buttons,which,clientX,clientY,detail,relatedTarget,screenX,screenY,deltaX,deltaY,deltaZ,deltaMode,animationstart,animationend,animationiteration,animationName,elapsedTime,propertyName,elapsedTime,transitionend,onerror,onmessage,onopen,ononline,onoffline,onstorage,onshow,ontoggle,onpopstate,ontouchstart,ontouchmove,ontouchend,ontouchcancel,persisted,javascript"; 
$jsxss = explode(",",$jsxss);
foreach($_POST as $k=>$v)
{
    if(is_array($v))
    {
        foreach($v as $Kk=>$Vv)
        {
            $Vv = preg_replace ( "'<script[^>]*?>.*?</script>'si", "", $Vv );
            $Vv = str_replace($jsxss,"",$Vv);
            $Vv = str_replace (array("*","\\"), "", $Vv );
            $Vv = strip_tags($Vv);
            $Vv = htmlentities($Vv, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
            $Vv = htmlspecialchars($Vv, ENT_QUOTES);
            $_POST[$k][$Kk] = $Vv;
        }
    }
    ELSE
    {
        //Сначала удаляем любые скрипты для защиты от xss-атак
        $v = preg_replace ( "'<script[^>]*?>.*?</script>'si", "", $v );
        //Вырезаем все известные javascript события для защиты от xss-атак
        $v = str_replace($jsxss,"",$v);
        //Удаляем экранированание для защиты от SQL-иньекций
        $v = str_replace (array("*","\\"), "", $v );
        //Экранируем специальные символы в строках для использования в выражениях SQL
        $v = mysql_real_escape_string( $v );
        //Удаляем другие лишние теги.   
        $v = strip_tags($v);
        //Преобразуеv все возможные символы в соответствующие HTML-сущности
        $v = htmlentities($v, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
        $v = htmlspecialchars($v, ENT_QUOTES);
        //Перезаписываем GET массив
        $_POST[$k] = $v;
    }

}
```

Тоже самое я сделал по аналогии с  _GET и _COOKIE
Основные недостатки.

1) У меня так и не вышло обработать, а точнее перезаписать их внутри функции и передать _POST, _GET и _COOKIE в качестве переменных, а главное, как следствие, обработать многомерные массивы данных рекурсивно. Соответственно $_POST[][], $_POST[][][] и тд уже обработать не выйдет и каждый такой массив надо вставлять отдельно. Массив может быть бесконечно большой, а код получится бесконечно громозкий.

2) Не охота убирать функцию mysql_real_escape_string ведь никогда не знаешь, где ее забыли упомянуть, но возникает проблема излишнего экранирования символов.

3) strip_tags удаляет все теги. Мне бы не хотелось убирать все, а лишь самые опасные теги, но беда в том, что в дополнительных параметрах можно указать только теги, которые нужно оставить. Конечно, можно использовать регулярные выражения, но к сожалению, нет уверенности в том, что не забудешь что-нибудь важное, поэтому если у кого-то есть отличная замена этому, то предлагаю собрать все в кучу и избавиться от strip_tags

4) Ну и жду других советов по данному вопросу.

Comment: Это вопиюще неправильный подход. Фильтровать данные нужно не на входе, а на выходе — в тех местах, где может случиться что-то потенциально небезопасное. А до тех пор пришедшие от пользователя строки абсолютно безопасны и ни в каких манипуляциях не нуждаются.

Comment: Просто используйте шаблонизаторы и PDO, которые автоматически вас защищают — и у вас больше никогда в жизни не будет проблем ни с XSS-атаками, ни с SQL-инъекциями.

Comment: @andreymal PDO и шаблонизаторы не защищают от xss и sql-инъекций автоматически. Просто с ними немного проще писать безопасный код.

Comment: @ЕгорБанин ну если стрелять себе в ногу, обходить штатные средства работы с запросами и отключать включенное по умолчанию экранирование, то да, не защитят. Но я надеюсь, что среднестатистический разработчик хотя бы немного адекватен и осознаёт что пишет :)

Answer (score 4):

Если бы ваша универсальная защита была бы на этом сайте, то вы бы не смогли опубликовать свой вопрос. Все специальные символы и последовательности имеют своё специальное значение только в специальных контекстах. Базе данных не страшны примеры js-кода, в HTML нет ничего криминального в тексте "DROP TABLE".

Таким образом вам нужно экранировать данные в конкретных случаях.

- В SQL-запросах. Для этого можно использовать возможности `PDO` или других библиотек.
- В HTML -- `htmlspecialchars`.
- где-то ещё, где вы и не подозреваете (например в регулярных выражениях -- `preg_quote`)

Получается что для каждого случая нужная своя функция экранирования. И эти функции уже есть, их нужно только использовать. Обработка всего и сразу приведёт к проблемам.

Comment: Кроме прочего, подумайте ещё и о двойном экранировании. То есть, что если в какой-то части кода разработчик всё-таки заэкранирует значение из $_POST? А там уже заэкранированные вами данные. Беда.